# What are these horizontal lines across both screens indicative of?

Tags: graphics-card

[image]

A friend sent me this picture asking if she needs a new graphics card and it seems probable but I'm no expert and figured I'd ask the pros.

I'm having her reinstall the graphics card right now just to make sure everything's snug. I don't think I can have her reinstall the video driver with her screens like this though. Is this probably a bad GPU?

Comment: Is there a good / regular picture right after booting, during POST or in the (bios) config? Cables & monitors work OK with a different computer?

Comment: @Xen2050 She swapped the monitor and wires, we can rule that out. I'll get a video of the boot process

Comment: @Xen2050 I guess the plot thickens because when I asked her to video the screens duringbstart up she said sometimes it freezes and won't boot, sometimes it has these lines, sometimes it just blanks out, and sometimes it bluescreens. RIP

Comment: i had a video card that did this when it got hot, and it got hot REAL quick because the heatsink became detached

Comment: Getting a solid normal blue screen error sounds like the monitor(s?) and video card work OK, at least for a low resolution... booting in "safe mode" might work, at least to see if it works, maybe install different drivers. But random freezes and BSOD might point to other problems... test for bad ram? I'd try with only one monitor at a time, maybe even the combination is bad